# What "data" should you pass with React context

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

The React doc's say that [context is for passing data around without prop drilling](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

I get that usually that "data" will be some kind of state.
What other kind of data might you want to use context for?

Specifically, we have a service layer object that has a bunch of methods to interact with APIs and external libraries. Is there any benefit of wrapping these objects in context?

They seem to work fine just accessing them like any regular import but colleagues are saying they should be wrapped in context.

Answer (score 0):

Context is useful to share data that won't often change across component avoiding props drilling.

For instance, let's say you have a modal component and you want to be able to control the open state of your modal in many components, you may want to provide a context for your modal component (that what [react-modal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-modal))

For your question about benefits of wrapping services in contexts there is no real answer, it depend of your project structure and your state management,
if you're request consume context based data (token, cache or ids) why not but if you use other state management system and your services relies on it, I would say there is no reason to wrap your services in context.